# How to get object from JSON which has specific properties using lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a JSON string as follows:

```
var empJSON = {
    "Emp1":{
        id:"emp123124",
        name:"xyz"
    },
    "Emp2":{
        id:"emp12654",
        name:"abx"
    }
};
```

The structure of JSON is fixed.

I want to fetch the current object which has a specific id.

e.g. The Emp1 object where id is "emp123124".

How can I do this easily using lodash?

Comment: That's not JSON but a plain old object: [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: What have you tried? Please, can you show us [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`_.find()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find)

*Iterates over elements of collection, returning the first element predicate returns truthy for. The predicate is invoked with three arguments: (value, index|key, collection).*

---

```js
var empJSON = {
  "Emp1": {
    id: "emp123124",
    name: "xyz"
  },
  "Emp2": {
    id: "emp12654",
    name: "abx"
  }
};

var id = "emp12654";
var result = _.find(empJSON, function(emp) { return emp.id === id });

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use native JavaScript [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) methods.

```js
var empJSON = {
  "Emp1": {
    id: "emp123124",
    name: "xyz"
  },
  "Emp2": {
    id: "emp12654",
    name: "abx"
  }
};

var id = 'emp12654';
 
var res = empJSON[Object.keys(empJSON).find(function(k) {
  return empJSON[k].id == id;
})];

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I know - I realised that, hence why i deleted the comment 2 seconds later

Answer (score 0):

just use `_.find` shorthand

```
_.find(empJSON, {id: 'emp123124'})
```